# Vimeo API - Alphabetical sort for Album via API

Tags: api, sorting, vimeo, alphabetical

Please forgive my bad English. Excuse Me.

My principal API tools is `vimeo.albums.getAll` function.

The Vimeo site have the option:

```
Sort: Date Alphabetical Videos Durations
```

But the **API** only is option:

```
sort string Method to sort by: newest, oldest, most_played, most_commented, or most_liked.
```

I need get in Alphabetical via API.
Appreciate any help.

Please sorry my BAD English, very BAD.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using (the Advanced API, which uses vimeo.albums.getAll) Was deprecated almost a year ago.

The new API (developer.vimeo.com/api) supports alphabetical search at the endpoint `/users/{user_id}/albums?sort=alphabetical`